# Spring Data Pagination with very custom sorting

Tags: database, sorting, pagination, spring-data

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling in my application, with the use of spring data pagination mechanism.

In my application I have an entity which is kind of like an event, let's call it Event and it has a property of date.

A user has events. He has some events that are going to happen in the future, some that are already expired and additionally each user has one unique "default" event that has no date - it is represented as null in the db.

In my app I need to display the events in two sections:

a) active events - events that are going to happen in the future + the default event

b) expired events - the events, whose date  is already in the past.

The way it worked so far was that I would request all the events for the user from the db and then, having all of them, I would apply custom sorting in the client app:

a) the active events are to be sorted in ascending order - first the ones that are closest to today and then the newer ones. The "null" event goes to the bottom of this list.

b) the past events are to be sorted in descending order - first the ones that closest to today and then the older ones.

Is there any way I can achieve that without separating the two calls, so that I have paginated results that are sorted this way?

I do realize it may be too complicated and I am sorry for that.

Thanks in advance,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `PageImpl<T>` in Spring and add your respective data list to it.

```
public Page<EventEntity> getEvents(Pageable pageable){
    long pageSize = 30l;
    // Sort this in ASC while querying from DB
    List<EventEntity> list1 = eventRepository.findByEventType(EventType.active);
    List<EventEntity> list2 = eventRepository.findByEventType(EventType.default);
    // Sort this in DESC while querying from DB
    List<EventEntity> list3 = eventRepository.findByEventType(EventType.expired);

    // Add all the data into a final List
    List<EventEntity> finalList = new ArrayList<EventEntity>();
    finalList.addAll(list1);
    finalList.addAll(list2);
    finalList.addAll(list3);
    return new PageImpl<>(finalList, pageable, pageSize);
}
```